# how to make divisible by 3 and 5

Tags: javascript, html

i'm new to Javascript and our teacher gave us an exercise for home that I don't know how to continue

what do i have to do: make an input where we write a number N and shows all the numbers between 1 and N that are divisible by 3 and 5.

my code so far, I don't know what to do further:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function calcSum() {
  m = parseInt(document.mainForm.calculation.value);
  var sum = 0;
  if (m > 1) {
    for (var i = 0; i <= m; i++) {
      if (i % 3 == 0) {
        sum += i;
      }
      if (i % 5 == 0) {
        sum += i;
      }             
    }
  }
  document.mainForm.sum.value = sum;
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="mainForm">
        <input type="text" name="calculation" /> <br/>
        <input type="button" value="Process" onclick="javascript: calcSum()" />
        <input type="text" name="sum" readonly="readonly"/>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Why are you calculating a sum if you want a list of numbers?

Comment: Hint: if a number is divisible by *both* 3 and 5, then it's divisible by `3 * 5`.

Comment: hint: start with empty array and push into it within conditional

Answer (score 0):

Just use a loop to get all numbers divisible by 15 *(3 times 5)* and push them into an Array:

```js
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var max = parseInt(document.getElementById('max').value, 10);
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = calc_divisibles(max).join('<br>');
}, false);

function calc_divisibles(max) {
  var res = [];
  for (var i = 15; i <= max; i += 15) res.push(i);
  return res;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="max" placeholder="Enter a number">
<button id="btn">Click here</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Comment: I keep getting this error when I try the code Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Comment: @maxxi That's because you don't have any element with the ID "btn" as I do in my HTML. Add an ID to your button, and change the ID in the JS accordingly.

Comment: I do have id="btn" in my button and document.getElementById('btn') , just like in your post, am i missing something??